# OpenGL skips main function on visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glut

I am trying to run the following c++ opengl code in Visual Studio 2010. I am using openglut as opengl utility toolkit.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gl\openglut.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void RenderScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
}

void SetupRC()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "Test1" << endl;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow("Simple");
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);

    SetupRC();

    glutMainLoop();

    cout << "Test2" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Code compiles correctly but when I run without debugging nothing is shown on console. When I create a breakpoint at first cout statement and run with debug it doesn't stop at breakpoint. It seems to be skipping the main function. After I comment out the glut,gl statements between 2 cout statements and clean solution then it behaves correctly(stops at breakpoint). If I don't clean solution it doesn't behave correctly but I see that visual studio compiling the code after I do the changes. These weird behaviors only happen when I include opengl code. I don't need to clean solution after I make changes normally. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Doesn't Glut have its own main method? And you, as the implmentor, are just supposed to implement certain other methods? (Speaking from memory, and it's been a long while since I looked at Glut, so could be completely wrong/thinking of a different framework...)

Comment: I am new to opengl but I took this example directly from the book "OpenGL SuperBible 4th Edition" so it should be correct.

Comment: @TJMonk15: No GLUT does not provide a main.

Comment: @TJMonk15: No, GLUT doesn't have its own Main. If OpenGLUT does, then that's a deviation from the standard GLUT laid out.

Comment: I can try any suggestions to figure out what the problem is

Comment: Try pressing F11. That should start debugging and immediately break on the first statement. See where, if at all, it breaks.

Comment: Are you compiling with UNICODE defined? If so, you should use `_tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])` as main entry point.

Comment: @Pavel: No. Character set is defined as "Not Set" in project properties

Comment: @SionSheevok: Same thing happens when I press F11. Visual studio gets into debugging state for about 2 seconds, opens and closes console window without doing anything. I check that breakpoint exist in the breakpoints window.

Comment: I installed and tried freeglut but same thing happens.

Comment: Which entry point is set in project settings?

Comment: @PavelZhuravlev: Entry point is set to nothing but "no entry point" is set to no. I think the problem is not related to that. I need to find why this happens when I include the opengl code.

Comment: @AlpHancioglu is the configuration type set to `Application (.exe)`  and the subsystem to `Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)`?

Comment: @AlpHancioglu well then it seems that linking with openglut causes some kind of malfunction. Have you tried linking it statically or dynamically? Also did you compile it from source, if not I'd recommend that.

Comment: What do you mean by static or dynamic? I followed the steps here http://www.divms.uiowa.edu/~cwyman/classes/common/howto/winGLUT.html for compiling it in Visual Studio by using header and library files from http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel  (freeglut 2.8.0 MSVC Package)

Comment: @AlpHancioglu I'm sorry, I thought you were using: http://openglut.sourceforge.net/ because your second sentence was `I am using openglut as opengl utility toolkit.` Freeglut doesn't appear to have a statically linked version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I should have put the freeglut.dll file near the executable. Before I put it into system32 folder not to clutter things. The code works now. Visual Studio should have given some kind of error but it showed no error or warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the function `glutMainLoop` *will not return*. When you close the window, that function will halt the application entirely. So nothing after that function call will ever get executed.

Even if later code were to get executed, it would only happen when you have closed the window. `glutMainLoop` is what sits and waits for you to do things to your window. It calls the callback functions you have registered when events happen in the window (mouse moved, mouse clicked, display needs updating, timers, etc).

Think of it as a `while(true)` loop.

Comment: I know all that but if you have read carefully I said that it doesn't break at the first cout statement which is the first statement in the main function, before all glut code.